# Duda con respecto a "nonlocal" con una función "nieto"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buen día,

Haciendo pruebas con `nonlocal` encontré un comportamiento que no entiendo del todo, espero que alguien me pueda explicar ya que no sé si no entendí bien o si es un `bug` de `Python` (Estoy utilizando Python 3.10.5)

Según lo que dice la ayuda de `Python` al ejecutar el comando `help('nonlocal')` (Agrego parte de la cita y abajo la traducción según mi interpretación)

> The "nonlocal" statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to
> previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding
> globals.

Entiendo que `nonlocal` hace que los identificadores declarados sean relacionadas con la variable con el mismo nombre en el **ámbito/alcance (`scope`) más cercano**, excluyendo el ámbito global.

La misma ayuda hace referencia al [`PEP 3104`](https://peps.python.org/pep-3104/) donde se menciona:

> In most languages that support nested scopes, code can refer to or rebind (assign to) any name in the nearest enclosing scope.

Dicioendo que, en la mayoría de los lenguajes que soporta alcances (`scopes`) anidados, el código puede hacer referencia a cualquier nombre del **ámbito (`scope`) que lo contiene**.

Y en la página [`GeeksforGeeks`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nonlocal-keyword/) se describe de la siguiente forma:

> Python nonlocal keyword is used to reference a variable in the nearest scope. The nonlocal keyword won’t work on local or global variables and therefore must be used to reference variables in another scopes except the global and local one. The nonlocal keyword is used in nested functions to reference a variable in the parent function.

Donde entiendo que, La palabra clave `nonlocal` de `Python` se utiliza para referenciar una variable en el **ámbito más cercano**. La palabra clave `nonlocal` no funcionará en variables locales o globales y por lo tanto debe usarse para referenciar variables en otros ámbitos excepto el global y el local. **La palabra clave `nonlocal` se utiliza en funciones anidadas para referenciar una variable en la función padre**.

### Mi duda:

Lo que entiendo de todo esto es que `nonlocal` se utiliza para referenciar variables en una función anidada con las variables de la función que la contiene **(Función padre)** y que si no existiera una variable con el nombre del identificador entonces se devolvería:

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'nombre' found
```

Donde `nombre` sería el nombre del identificador dado.

Mi duda es, al probar `nonlocal` con tres funciones anidadas, declarar una variable local en la función `uno` y utilizar `nonlocal` en la función `tres` (Es decir, la función **"nieto"** de `uno`) ¿Por qué razón no devuelve el siguiente error?

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'm' found
```

Yo esperaría que apareciera el error ya que `m` no es una variable local de la función `dos` que sería el **ámbito más cercano**, tal como lo mencionan los textos anteriores, en cambio permite modificar la variable local de la función `uno` y no muestra ningún error. ¿Es este el comportamiento correcto?

Código con el que estóy haciendo las pruebas:

```
def uno():
    m = 1
    print('uno', m)
    
    def dos():
        print('dos', m)
        
        def tres():
            nonlocal m
            m = 3
            print('tres', m)
        
        tres()
        
    dos()
    print('uno', m)

uno()
```

Esto devuelve:

```
uno 1
dos 1
tres 3
uno 3
```

¿Existe alguna forma de limitar `nonlocal` únicamente a la función padre?

### Actualización 2022/08/17

Después de la respuesta de Abulafia encontré un buen [artículo](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-nonlocal/) que explica lo siguiente:

> - The enclosing scopes of inner functions are called nonlocal scopes.
> - Use the nonlocal keyword to modify the variable from the nonlocal scopes.
> - And Python will look up the nonlocal variables in the enclosing local scopes chain. It won’t search for the variable in the global
>   scope.

Traducción:

- Los ámbitos que encierran las funciones internas se denominan ámbitos no locales (`nonlocal`).
- Utiliza la palabra clave `nonlocal` para modificar la variable de los ámbitos no locales.
- `Python` buscará las variables no locales en la cadena de ámbitos locales adjuntos (Es decir los que encierran a la función), excepto en  el ámbito global (Y local, por lo que menciona la documentación oficial y el mismo artículo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El comportamiento es el esperado, no se trata de ningún bug, sino en todo caso de una confusa explicación en la documentación, puesto que para entender la frase:

> Python nonlocal keyword is used to reference a variable in the nearest scope
> [...] The nonlocal keyword is used in nested functions to reference a variable in the parent function.

es necesario tener claro qué significa para Python el concepto *scope*, lo cual está relacionado con el modelo de ejecución de Python, cuándo (y por tanto dónde) se *crean* las variables y cómo se busca un nombre para resolverlo de modo que se pueda obtener el objeto al que el nombre referencia.

Todo eso viene explicado con más detalle en el apartado [4.2.2](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html?highlight=scope#resolution-of-names) de la parte del manual titulada [Execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html).

Trataré de explicarlo con más detalle.

### Scope (o alcance)

El *scope* es la zona de un programa desde la que se puede usar un símbolo de modo que éste sea resuelto a un objeto sin ambigüedades. Un nombre de variable sólo puede ser accedido desde su *scope*.

El *scope* de un símbolo depende de dónde haya sido **definido** ese símbolo. En el caso, por ejemplo, de una clase depende de dónde aparezca la palabra `class`, o en el caso de una función o método depende de dónde aparezca la palabra `def`. Pero para simplificar vamos a centrarnos en el caso de las variables.

Debido a que Python es un lenguaje dinámico en el que las variables no se declaran antes de usarlas, una variable es **definida** en el punto en que sea **asignada por primera vez**.

Bajo este punto de vista está claro que se tienen dos posibles *scopes*. Si la variable se asignó fuera de cualquier función, en un módulo, su *scope* será global (a nivel de ese módulo). Si se asignó dentro de una función su *scope* será local (y alcanzará esa función y todas las que tenga anidadas).

Así, en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
def uno():
    m = 1
    print('uno', m)
    
    def dos():
        print('dos', m)

        def tres():
            print('tres', m)
```

vemos que la asignación `m=1` crea la variable `m` en el *scope* de la función `uno()` el cual incluye también las funciones anidadas `dos()` y `tres()`, es por eso que podemos usar la variable `m` tanto desde dentro de `dos()` como desde dentro de `tres()`. La variable es encontrada (y el objeto al que apunta, que es el entero 1 puede ser usado) desde cualquiera de esas funciones.

Pero cabe la posibilidad de que un mismo símbolo `m` esté definido en varios "niveles". Por ejemplo podría haber una `m` global. En ese caso esta `m` global no podrá ser accedida desde dentro de las funciones, debido a la existencia de la `m` local, que tiene "prioridad". Esto nos lleva a hablar de la resolución de nombres

### Resolución de nombres

Python sigue la regla denominada LEGB, que son las iniciales de "Local", "Enclosing", "Global" y "Builtin", pues ese es el orden de los *scopes* en los que buscará un símbolo cuando se intente acceder a él. Así, cuando encuentre una sentencia como ésta:

```
print("tres", m)
```

necesitará encontrar el símbolo `m`, y para ello mirará primero en el *scope* local (en este caso no lo encuentra), después en el *enclosing scope* que es un *scope* que sólo existe en el caso de las funciones anidadas y que contiene todos los nombres que hayan sido creados dentro de ese *scope* (lo que incluye todas las funciones "ancestro", desde su padre hasta su tatarabuelo). En este caso `m` es encontrada en el *enclosing scope*.

Aquí es donde resulta confuso lo del *nearest scope*. ¿No debería ser el *nearest* sólo el padre? Lo que ocurre es que el padre no ha creado esa varirable, o dicho de otro modo, esa variable no existe en el padre, por lo que no puede tomarse de él. Sí existe en cambio en el abuelo (es local en el abuelo), y por tanto el abuelo es el *nearest scope* que contiene esa variable.

La clave es esta frase de la documentación (del apartado 4.4.2, la negrita es mía):

> The nonlocal statement causes corresponding names to refer to **previously bound variables** in the nearest enclosing function scope.

La variable `m` está ligada (*bound*) a la función `uno()`, pero no a la función `dos()`. Así que el *nearest enclosing function* que tiene esa *previously bound variable* es `uno()`, y así `m` se resuelve desde `tres()` como la variable que fue creada en `uno()`

### Declaración `nonlocal`

Cabe preguntarse ¿para qué sirve entonces la declaración `nonlocal` si ya estamos viendo que el algoritmo LEGB resuelve correctamente `m` sin necesidad de declarar `m` como `nonlocal`?

La razón es que si la función `tres()` intentara asignar algo a `m` así:

```
def uno():
    m = 1
    print('uno', m)

    def dos():
        print('dos', m)

        def tres():
            print('tres', m)
            m = 0
```

tendríamos un problema (y un error desconcertante). El problema es que, debido a que **ahora hay una asignación a `m` detro de `tres()`, resulta que se ha creado una nueva variable `m`, que será `local` dentro de la función `tres()`. Recordemos que al asignar una variable *se crea*, y su *scope* queda asociado al lugar donde se creó.

Por tanto la asignación `m=0` estará definiendo una variable `m` local, accesible sólo dentro de la función `tres()`. El cero no se estaría guardando en la variable `m` de la función `uno()`.

Y lo que es peor, el `print("tres", m)` fallaría con un extraño error:

```
local variable 'm' referenced before assignment
```

Esto se debe a que en la línea del `print("tres", m)`, la variable `m` es la versión `local` de la función `tres()`, pero *todavía no tiene un valor asignado* (puesto que es la línea siguiente la que le asigna un cero). De ahí el desconcertante error.

Esto podemos arreglarlo así:

```
def uno():
    m = 1
    print('uno', m)
    
    def dos():
        print('dos', m)
        
        def tres():
            nonlocal m
            print('tres', m)
            m = 0
```

Al escribir `nonlocal m` símplemente estamos diciendo a Python que si ve una asignación `m = loquesea`, no cree una nueva versión local de `m`, sino que la trate como la habría tratado si en vez de asignarle un valor simplemente hubiéramos querido consultar su valor. Es decir, que aplicará la regla LEGB para resolver el objeto al que se refiere. Así el cero se asignará a la variable `m` de `uno()`.

### Respondiendo directamente a tus preguntas

#### Primera

> Mi duda es, al probar nonlocal con tres funciones anidadas, declarar una variable local en la función uno y utilizar nonlocal en la función tres (Es decir, la función "nieto" de uno) ¿Por qué razón no devuelve el siguiente error?
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'm' found
> ```

Pues porque sí que ha encontrado un *binding* para la varible `m`, puesto que la ha encontrado en el *enclosing scope* como se ha explicado antes.

#### Segunda

> ¿Existe alguna forma de limitar nonlocal únicamente a la función padre?

No. Pero ¿para qué podría servir algo así? Si quieres que la función padre tenga su propia "versión" de `m`, basta que le asignes un valor dentro de la función padre. Eso la creará. Si en cambio la función padre no tiene su propia "versión" ¿qué sentido tiene tratar de declararla como `nonlocal` en la hija para que eso provoque un error?

Comment: Muchas gracias Abulafia, la segunda pregunta no es en realidad para hacer algo sino que iba relacionada a mi duda de por qué no aparecía el error. Yo creo que, como mencionas, la documentación no es del todo clara ya que debería decir que la variable referida en el identificador va a ser buscada en todas las funciones contenedoras y excepto en los ámbitos local y global.

Answer (score 2):

Siempre me parece un problema el alcance de las palabras, entendemos de forma distinta las mismas expresiones, soy muy malo explicando así que perdón por como lo pueda decir. Voy a extender en principio tu código y haciendo una omisión:

```
def uno():
    m=1 
    def dos():
        print('dos', m)
        def tres():
            print('tres',m)
            def cuatro():
                print('cuatro',m)
            cuatro()
        tres()
    dos()
    
uno()
```

ahora en base a esto que pusiste:

> Yo esperaría que apareciera el error ya que m no es una variable local
> de la función dos que sería el ámbito más cercano,

sin embargo yendo más profundo en el anidamiento lo mismo encuentra la variable, ya que el acercamiento(enclosing) o lo encerrado en lo anidado es subir desde lo heredado hasta el padre, esto es obvio porque m no está declarada en ninguna función subsecuente al padre.Nunca leí que esa limitación exista en funciones anidadas, aunque no es que lea tanto.

modificando un poco el código:

```
def uno():
    m=1 
    def dos():
        print('dos', m)
        def tres():
            print('tres',m)
            def cuatro():
                m=4
                print('cuatro',m)
            cuatro()
        tres()
    dos()
    print('uno',m)
uno()
```

está claro que solo la modifica en el ámbito local o cercano, o sea la lectura es una cosa y la modificación es otra.
Si agregamos a la función cuatro:
nonlocal m
No solo la lee sino la modifica, en resumen lo "cercano" está definido en funciones anidadas desde el padre en adelante.

Con respecto al error esperado te has dado la respuesta:

> La palabra clave nonlocal no funcionará en variables locales o
> globales y por lo tanto debe usarse para referenciar variables en
> otros ámbitos excepto el global y el local. La palabra clave nonlocal
> se utiliza en funciones anidadas para referenciar una variable en la
> función padre.

en código sería simplemente:

```
m=1
def uno():
    def dos():
        #etc.
```

donde m es global y deja de ser local, aunque este en la "primer función", por eso digo que deberían definir con exactitud cercano en las funciones anidadas.

> ¿Existe alguna forma de limitar nonlocal únicamente a la función
> padre?

No lo sé pero me parece que no, ya que cualquiera puede ser el padre en funciones anidadas, ya que es simplemente la que da origen, ejemplo:

```
def uno():
    # print(g) es claro que da error no está definida
    def dos():
        g=2
        print('dos', g)
        def tres():
            print('tres',g)
            def cuatro():
                nonlocal g
                g=4
                print('cuatro',g)
            cuatro()
        tres()
    dos()
    
uno()
```

Comment: Pero según lo que dice la documentación `nonlocal` actúa sobre la función más cercana que la contenga, `tres` "contiene" `g` porque la hereda de `dos` pero ¿Por qué al modificarla con `nonlocal` en `cuatro` no se limita al contenedor más cercano tal como dice la documentación?

Comment: quizá este enlace te explique mejor https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/simple_stmts.html